# spring cloud with common trustore for kafka in configs

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-config

I have spring-config-server inside which there is

```
main/resources/configs/app1
main/resources/configs/app2
main/resources/configs/app3
```

And inside each folder there are different settings like

```
app1-development.yml
app1-integration.yml
app1-production.yml
```

And now 1 of the applications, for example, the same app1, has certificates for Kafka, which it needs in its work.

If you put them in a container inside the application, everything works.
Like this

```
app1/src/main/resources/certs/truststore.jks
```

All the keys are inside that truststore.jks, for all environments. I want to put it from app1 to spring cloud

```
spring-config-server/src/main/resources/configs/app1/certs/truststore.jks
```

The settings are something like this

```
spring-config-server/src/main/resources/configs/app1/app1-development.yml

...
ssl:
trust-store-location: classpath:/certs/truststore.jks
...
```

But after starting app1 it doesn't find any certs. Why?

Comment: You can't reference something in config server with classpath. We don't have support for what you want to do

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Anyway, what is correct way to specify each keystore and/or path for it for each environment?